# Glossary WITHOUT location numbers

Tags: glossaries

I'm using Glossary package and its printing the glossary list with a number at the end of each item (I'm assuming its chapter number).

Is there a way NOT to print this number?

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I would have expected it is the page number. Anyway, there are many ways to produce glossaries in TeX. Can you show us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of how you get yours, please?

Comment: Note that the [`glossary` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossary) is obsolete and has been replaced by [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries).

Comment: With `glossaries`, I've never got a number.

Comment: It will only be the chapter number if you have used `counter=chapter`. The default is the page number.

Answer (score 4):

That's the [location or number list](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:numberlists). It can be suppressed with the package option `nonumberlist` (assuming you actually meant the [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package, not the obsolete [`glossary`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossary) package).

MWE (demonstrating the default behaviour):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}

\gls{sample} %page 1

\chapter{Another Sample}

\gls{sample}% page 2

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: Glossary sample an example. 1, 2]

Without number list:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}

\gls{sample} %page 1

\chapter{Another Sample}

\gls{sample}% page 2

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: Glossary sample an example.]

Alternatively:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}

\gls{sample} %page 1

\chapter{Another Sample}

\gls{sample}% page 2

\printglossary[nonumberlist]

\end{document}
```